# Prompts on top of popup windows in Xamarin and MAUI

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

I have discovered the limitation of displaying prompts when they are invoked from a popup window. Specifically verified with `CommunityToolkit.Maui` Popups.

Here's the details:

In the Map page I have this handler for the map clicked event:

```
void mapClicked(object sender, MapClickedEventArgs e) {
    var pin = new Pin {
            Label = "Here's where it is",
            Location = e.Location
        };
    map.Pins.Add(pin);
}
```

I wanted to allow the user to edit the pin label when clicking on the it, like so:

```
pin.InfoWindowClicked += async (s, args) => {
    string pinName = ((Pin)s).Label;
    await DisplayPromptAsync("Enter new label", "enter new label");
};
```

However, this didn't work as no `DisplayPrompt` was shown. I  tried running it in the main thread, to no avail either.

**UPDATE.** I've figured it out, see answer below.

Comment: are you sure your event handler is being called?

Comment: Yes, it gets called because I get a ```Debug.WriteLine``` out of it.

Comment: that code works for me in XF5 on iOS 16.1

Comment: Thanks, do you mean DisplayPromptAsync comes up?  Is it a Shell.Current.DisplayPromptAsync? (Incidentally, I use MAUI .NET 7).

Comment: I'm not using shell.  But the prompt came up and the Label of the Pin updated on the Map.

Comment: I think I've discovered the problem but I am not sure how to solve it.  I am bringing up the map in a popup (CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views.Popup) and that doesn't have a native DisplayPromptAsync method, so I was calling the Shell.Current for it.  Which doesn't work, evidently.  So I'd have to use the DisplayPromptAsync from the parent window (the one that I called the Popup from) but I don't know how to get to it.

Comment: `Shell.Current` should return the currently displayed page.  But it may not be possible to display a DisplayPrompt on top of a popup window.

Comment: Sigh... Sure looks like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arises when attempting to bring up the prompt from a  popup window. Evidently, one can't have a `DisplayPromptAsync` (or `DisplayAlert` for that matter) on top of a popup.

On a platform-specific level in `iOS` the error message reads:

`Attempt to present <UIAlertController> on <Microsoft_Maui_Controls_Platform_Compatibility_ShellFlyoutRenderer> (from <Microsoft_Maui_Controls_Platform_Compatibility_ShellFlyoutRenderer>) which is already presenting <CommunityToolkit_Maui_Core_Views_MauiPopup>.`